# Requiring a certain trait -> Self type annotation?

Tags: scala, self-type

I'd like to require a case class to also implement at least one of certain traits.

I thought, I could use self-type annotations like this:

```
case class DisqualifiedDate(override val paths: Set[DatePath],
     override val cal: Calendar) extends CalendricDate(paths,cal){

     this: DateError =>

     val stringPrefix = "DisqualifiedDate"
 }

sealed trait DateError
trait Circular extends DateError
trait Contradictory extends DateError
trait Inaccessible extends DateError
```

However instantiating with a mixin doesn't compile. So, when I do:

```
val date = new DisqualifiedDate(Set(datePath),cal) with Circular
```

this doesn't compile.

Am I doing something wrong or this the whole approach flawed?

SOLVED: It works perfectly with a normal class, i.e. non-case class. I'm not sure why this is so, but I'm OK with that.

Comment: self-type means a concrete class must implement it. Did you intend to extend DisqualifiedDate later? The pun on intend/extend was unintentional.

Comment: I want to make sure that a DisqualifiedDate also bears at least one type of DateError. So the input doesn't work, something must be wrong about it. DateError should mark what exactly happened here. It should be possible for a DisqualifiedDate to have more than one type of error. I do not want to extend the DisqualifiedDate itself.

Comment: Probably you're doing something wrong and the approach is flawed. "bear" a type of DateError means that info is encoded in the type or as a term (that is, a member that says which DateError). self-type means you have a DisqualifiedDate with Circular, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stand-alone case class (i.e. without `extends` or mixins) can't be self typed.

Think about it. A `case class` is both a class definition and a singleton instantiation. A self-type reference means that instantiation can't take place without the specified self-type mixed in.

You either have to make it a class definition without the automatic singleton creation, or mix in the required trait when the case class is defined.

```
class DisqualifiedDate(override val paths: Set[DatePath],
                       override val cal: Calendar
                      ) extends CalendricDate(paths,cal) {
  this: DateError =>
  . . .
```

Or ...

```
case class DisqualifiedDate(override val paths: Set[DatePath],
                            override val cal: Calendar
                           ) extends CalendricDate(paths,cal) with DateError {
  this: DateError =>  // now redundant
  . . .
```

Comment: Your solution appears correct, and doing it the first way is what I want. I was aware that I have to do a mixin each time. That is exactly what I wanted. But it doesn't work with case classes.